# How to export a Bezier Curve into Unreal Engine 5?

Tags: export, bezier-curves, import, unreal-engine

I'm having trouble trying to export three Bezier curves into Unreal Engine 5. My mesh is a monster that has tubes coming out of his helmet into other areas of his body. The curves move dynamically when animating so Bezier curves are the only things I can think of to make it look realistic. However, when I export the mesh to Unreal Engine 5, the Bezier curves do not import. Ive tried *FBX*, *GLD*, *ABC*, DataMax for unreal, and any other format that you can think of. I've tinkered with countless settings trying to get it to export. I've applied all my transforms in Blender to make sure the scaling was right. I even translated the units from Blender to Unreal. I have spent hours digging through the internet with no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

[image: The white tubes are the ones that wont import/export]

Comment: You will not be able to export bezier curves that can dynamically deform. Common solutions for such thing are usually to either use normal mesh deformed by bones (bones can follow a curve if you want), or use the game engine's own curves/ropes dynamic systems.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for Unreal Engine 5 called Blender Curves Importer.

It specifically deals with exporting bezier curves and importing them into Unreal Engine as *USplineComponents*.

If you have a different type of curve in Blender, you can just convert it to bezier curves before exporting and importing in Unreal Engine 5. I think it maybe useful for your case.

https://youtu.be/HKUX5LKELMQ

Answer (score 0):

Convert curves into mesh (in any way, modifier, extrude or bevel, its not important).

#### You can animate in 2 ways:

##### Rig and Bones

But I guess its not an option in this case.

##### Shape keys

Define shape keys in blender. Constraints do not work unfortunely.
Export FBX and to Unreal engine you import model with "Morph targets".

Then you should be able to drive morth target in UnrealEning to match animation.